# Where is new wicket in maven repo?

Tags: wicket

I have received news about new wicket release (1.5.5), and can't fiend this artifact in central maven repository. In wicket.apache.org I see

```
To use in Maven:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
    <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But where did they deploy new maven? Or it's need some time, but why authors sent announcements about new version..

Comment: Its only 2h past the announcement.. give it some time

Comment: Sorry about this. I noticed that the staging repo is not released after sending the announcement ... It is in Maven central repo now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till now it seems like it's only available in the apache repository: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/public/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.5.5/